# Angular2 Material Design alpha.9-3 has '404 not found' for @angular/material

Tags: javascript, angular, systemjs, angular-material2

I have followed the instructions at angular material2 Getting Started to install @angular/material. Via Atom, I updated package.json, app.module, and beyond the Getting Started instructions, I updated systemjs.config, as follows: '@angular/material':'node_modules/@angular/material',

I get these errors:  zone.js:1274 GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/material/ 404 (Not Found)

(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/material(…)

I believe I have tracked the problem to the fact that many @angular folders have a bundle sub-folder containing the umd file, but the @angular/material folder does not have a bundle sub-folder. Hence, the 'unpacking' function can't find @angular/material/material.umd.js

systemjs is outside my comfort zone so I'm not sure of the above, but I am not able to solve the 404 problem with the new file structure of alpha.9-3  Here is relevant code (other components are not shown).

package.json

```
 "@angular/material": "2.0.0-alpha.9-3",
```

app.module

```
 import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
 @NgModule({
  imports: MaterialModule.forRoot(),
```

systemjs.config

```
  (function(global) {
    var map = {
      'app': 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
      // other libraries
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
      'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
      '@angular/material': 'node_modules/@angular/material',
    };
    var packages = {
      'app': { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
      'rxjs':{ defaultExtension: 'js' },
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    };
    var ngPackageNames = [
     'common',
     'compiler',
     'core',
     'forms',
     'http',
     'platform-browser',
     'platform-browser-dynamic',
     'platform-server',
     'router',
     'upgrade',
    ]; //adding 'material' to the array causes a different 404 error
    function packIndex(pkgName) {
      packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    function packUmd(pkgName) {
      packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
    ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig); 
    var config = {
      map: map,
      packages: packages
    };
    System.config(config);

  })(this); //end of function(global)
```

I have checked my folder/file structure and @angular/material/material.umd.js is definitely there.  How do I get rid of the 404 not found?

Comment: The angular-material tag should be removed since this doesn't relate to that library for Angular 1.x.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the following from `map`

<strike>'@angular/material': 'node_modules/@angular/material',</strike>

Add `material` to `ngPackageNames` array:

```
var ngPackageNames = [
 ...
 'material'
];
```

And then replace your `packUmd` function with

```
function packUmd(pkgName) {
   packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { 
     main: (pkgName !== 'material' ? 'bundles/' : '') + pkgName + '.umd.js', 
     defaultExtension: 'js' 
   };
}
```

After that it should work

Or use this config like in angular2 quick start:

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
      '@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',
      '@angular/material': 'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js'

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Comment: Yes, 2 good solutions in 1 answer. Both work. The individual Material components, e.g., toolbar, have to also be removed from app.module.  I like your 2nd solution because its literal characteristics show what happens.  Double thanks.

Comment: Is this uptodate?