# Can I use Angular Material 2.0.0-alpha.9-3 with angular 2.1?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I try to user angular/material ^2.0.0-alpha.9-3 with Angular 2.1, but I get the exceptions:

> zone.js:1274 GET http://localhost:3000/@angular/material 404 (Not Found)
>
> (index):16 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/@angular/material(…)

I have just created project using instruction on "Angular2 Quickstart" and run the command: "npm install --save @angular/material". After this command the folder "material" in node_modules/@angular was added.

my package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "user-manager",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/LICENSE"
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-alpha.9-3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.1.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.5",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",
    "typings": "^1.4.0"
  }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }   from './components/app/app.component';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
    imports:      [ BrowserModule, MaterialModule.forRoot() ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Can you help me, pls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

Since 2.0.0-beta.1 rebar-teacup

```
'@angular/material': 'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js'
```

**Previous version**

Change your systemjs config like:

```
map: {
  app: 'app',
  '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
  ...
  '@angular/material': 'npm:@angular/material/material.umd.js', <== add this line
},
```

See also [Angular2 Material Design alpha.9-3 has '404 not found' for @angular/material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39965524/angular2-material-design-alpha-9-3-has-404-not-found-for-angular-material)